# curl POST returning error 503 in cloud linux instance, while working on local mac

Tags: curl, ethereum, digital-ocean, http-status-code-503

**Describe the bug**

curl POST request fails with 503 in cloud (Digital Ocean) Ubuntu 18.04 instance, while the same setup works on a local mac (10.13.4).

Is there something cloud specific that is causing the error code?

**To Reproduce**

Open 2 terminals.

1) start a parity ethereum node and make the JSON-RPC port listen at localhost:18545

```
$ parity --light --jsonrpc-port 18545 --jsonrpc-hosts="all"
```

2) start a proxy with

```
$ lighttpd -f misc/lighttpd.conf
```

, which will forward incoming IPV6 port 8545 requests to IPV4 18545 and translate from HTTP chunked-encoding to Content-length. Then execute:

```
$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json"  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":987}' [::1]:8545
```

**Expected result**

On local mac:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"Parity-Ethereum//v2.5.0-beta-b52ac2066-20190408/x86_64-macos/rustc1.33.0","id":987}
```

**Actual Result**

On (Digital Ocean) Ubuntu 18.04:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>503 - Service Not Available</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>503 - Service Not Available</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Additional context**

-I get the same error in mac if I kill the parity process and then execute curl.

-[lighttpd.conf](https://github.com/AnyLedger/anyledger-wallet/blob/master/misc/lighttpd.conf)